# Conditionally exit action

Tags: yaml, github-actions

Newbie question about GitHub Actions and YAML configuration.

I have Action with one job and more steps that perform tests and open issue if they fail. It works well.

Now I want to make Action conditionally failed, in purpose to update Badge of that action.

Problem is in the last step "Handle exit" that is always called although there is a condition that works for the previous step but not in this.

Where I am wrong and how to conditionally do Step containing "run"?

```
name: Tests

on:
  - push

jobs:
  tests:
    name: Tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check out Git repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 14

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn install

      - name: Tests
        id: tests
        run: echo ::set-output name=failed::$(if expr length + "$(yarn test 2>&1 | grep fail -i)" > 0; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi)

      - name: Open Issue
        if: steps.tests.outputs.failed == 'true'
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        uses: JasonEtco/create-an-issue@v2

      - name: Handle exit
        if: steps.tests.outputs.failed == 'true'
        run: exit(1)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `exit(1)` or other non-zero exit-code?

Comment: Thank you I will update the question. It doesn't affect anyway